# tailwind doesn't with npm run dev

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I got a task to do which is to create some forms with tailwindcss but When I try to launch : npm run build, it does't work. Could you help me?

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 9
npm ERR! widgets@1.0.0 dev: `tailwind build css/tailwind.css -o build/css/tailwind.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 9
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the widgets@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/andresbolivar/.npm/_logs/2022-01-21T16_59_01_550Z-debug.log
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "widgets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tailwind build style.css -o /css/tailwind.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.15"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [install Tailwind CLI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) in order to execute `tailwind` commands:

```
# Using NPM?
npm install -D tailwindcss

# Using yarn?
yarn add tailwindcss -D
```

Also, it helps to check the error log (as mentioned in the message printed to your terminal) to find out a full stack trace of the error.